# Socket c++ application in Visual Studio does not work over ethernet connection between two computers

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, server, client

I'm currently working on a simple server/client application using C++ in Visual Studio to send a message from one computer to another via an Ethernet/LAN cable connection. I am using code for both client and server that I found online.

When I run the programs on the same computer, I can receive messages from the server.  However, if I run the client program on one computer and run the server program on another computer, I do not receive any messages.

Since I am just using an Ethernet cable to communicate between two computers, I set the IP addresses (from Local Network Sharing, Adapter settings, TCP/IPv4) to be specific for both computers, such that the server computer is 10.0.1.2 and the client computer is 10.0.1.1, both with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0.  And then, in the code, I use `addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.1.2")` for server and `addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.1.1")` for client accordingly.

But I am still having the problem of sending messages from one computer to another.

Here is the code:

```
/////////////////////Client Code///////////////////////////////

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  //Winsock Startup
  WSAData wsaData;
  WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
  if (WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData) != 0) //If WSAStartup returns anything other than 0, then that means an error has occured in the WinSock Startup.
  {
      MessageBoxA(NULL, "Winsock startup failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
      exit(1);
  }

  SOCKADDR_IN addr; //Address to be binded to our Connection socket
  int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr); //Need sizeofaddr for the connect function
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.1.1");
  addr.sin_port = htons(139); //Port = 139
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET; //IPv4 Socket

  SOCKET Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); //Set Connection socket
  if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeofaddr) != 0) //If we are unable to connect...
  {
      MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to Connect", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
      return 0; //Failed to Connect
  }
  std::cout << "Connected!" << std::endl;
  int rec = 0;
  char MOTD[256];
  while (1)
  {
      recv(Connection, MOTD, sizeof(MOTD), NULL); //Receive Message of the Day buffer into MOTD array
      std::cout << "MOTD:" << MOTD << std::endl;
      std::cout << "rec:" << rec << std::endl;
      rec++;
      Sleep(500);

  }
}
```

```
/////////////////////Server Code///////////////////////////////

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    //WinSock Startup
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    if (WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData) != 0) //If WSAStartup returns anything other than 0, then that means an error has occured in the WinSock Startup.
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "WinSock startup failed", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN addr; //Address that we will bind our listening socket to
    int addrlen = sizeof(addr); //length of the address (required for accept call)
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.1.2");
    addr.sin_port = htons(139); //Port
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET; //IPv4 Socket

    SOCKET sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL); //Create socket to listen for new connections
    bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)); //Bind the address to the socket
    listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN); //Places sListen socket in a state in which it is listening for an incoming connection. Note:SOMAXCONN = Socket Oustanding Max Connections
    int counter = 0;
    SOCKET newConnection; //Socket to hold the client's connection
    newConnection = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen); //Accept a new connection
    if (newConnection == 0) //If accepting the client connection failed
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to accept the client's connection." << std::endl;
    }
    else //If client connection properly accepted
    {
        std::cout << "Client Connected!" << std::endl;
        while (counter <100)
        {
            char MD[256] = "Hi there."; //Create buffer with message 
            send(newConnection, MD, sizeof(MD), NULL); //Send MD buffer
            counter++;

        }

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I really don't know what to do now.  I can ping from one computer to another, but I can not make it work to send a message from one computer to another via the Ethernet connection.

Comment: Shouldn't the IP address be the same? Anyway, if you run both server and client on the same PC on 127.0.0.1, it seems to work.

Comment: @KillzoneKid I tried to use the same IP address but it didn't work. I am trying to run server on one computer and client on another computer using ethernet cable connection from one to another

Comment: The client doesn't care about its own IP address - it should connect to the *server's* IP address, namely `10.0.1.2`. The server typically doesn't care about its own address either - it listens on `INADDR_ANY`.

Comment: 'Does mot work' is not a problem description, or 'I am still having the problem' either.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that the client is connecting to the wrong IP.  The server's IP is 10.0.1.2, but the client is trying to connect to 10.0.1.1 instead.  That is why it doesn't work across multiple computers.  The client needs to connect to the server's IP, not the client's IP.

Also, you are making several other mistakes in general.

On the server side, you are ignoring the return values of `bind()` and `listen()`, and `accept()` returns `INVALID_SOCKET` (-1) on error instead of 0.

On the client side, you are ignoring the return value of `recv()`.  It returns -1 on error, 0 on graceful disconnect, and > 0 for the number of bytes actually read.  You need to pay attention to that, especially when you are sending the read data to `std::cout`.  You are passing a `char[]` to `operator<<`, so the data must be null-terminated, but `recv()` does not do guarantee that.  So, either:

- add a null terminator to the end of the `char[]` data after reading it:

  ```
  int numRead = recv(Connection, MOTD, sizeof(MOTD)-1, NULL);
  if (numRead <= 0) break;
  MOTD[numRead] = 0; // <-- here
  std::cout << "MOTD:" << MOTD << std::endl;
  ```
- pass the `char[]` to `std::cin.write()` instead of `operator<<`, specifying the actual number of bytes read in the `count` parameter:

  ```
  int numRead = recv(Connection, MOTD, sizeof(MOTD), NULL);
  if (numRead <= 0) break;
  std::cout << "MOTD:";
  std::cout.write(MOTD, numRead); // <-- here
  std::cout << std::endl;
  ```

And your MOTD protocol is not very well designed in general.  The server is sending 256 bytes (if you are lucky, `send()` can send fewer bytes!) for every message, even though only 9 bytes are actually being used.  So you are wasting bandwidth.  The client is expecting to receive exactly 256 bytes every time (which is not guaranteed, as `recv()` may receive fewer bytes!).  A better design is to have the server send strings that have a terminating delimiter at the end, such as a line break or a null terminator, and then have the client read in a loop until it receives that delimiter, THEN process the data that has been received.

Try something more like this:

```
/////////////////////Client Code///////////////////////////////

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    //Winsock Startup
    WSAData wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 1), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) //If WSAStartup returns anything other than 0, then that means an error has occured in the WinSock Startup.
    {
        std::cout << "Winsock Startup Failed, Error " << iResult << std:endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN addr = {};
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET; //IPv4 Socket
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.1.2"); //Address to be connected to
    addr.sin_port = htons(139); //Port = 139

    SOCKET Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); //Create socket to establish new connection with
    if (Connection == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cout << "Failed to Create Socket, Error " << iResult << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return 1; //Failed to Connect
    }

    if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) //If we are unable to connect...
    {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cout << "Failed to Connect, Error " << iResult << std::endl;
        closesocket(Connection);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1; //Failed to Connect
    }

    std::cout << "Connected!" << std::endl;

    int rec = 0;
    char buf[256], *ptr, *start, *end;
    int numRead;
    std::string MOTD;

    int iExitCode = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        numRead = recv(Connection, buf, sizeof(buf), NULL); //Receive data
        if (numRead == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            iResult = WSAGetLastError();
            std::cout << "Failed to Read, Error " << iResult << std:endl;
            iExitCode = 1;
            break;
        }

        if (numRead == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Server disconnected!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        start = buf;
        end = buf + numRead;
        do
        {
            // look for MOTD terminator
            ptr = std::find(start, end, '\0');
            if (ptr == end)
            {
                // not found, need to read more...
                MOTD.append(start, end-start);
                break;
            }

            // terminator found, display current MOTD and reset for next MOTD...

            MOTD.append(start, ptr-start);

            std::cout << "MOTD:" << MOTD << std::endl;
            std::cout << "rec:" << rec << std::endl;

            rec++;
            MOTD = "";

            start = ptr + 1;
        }
        while (start < end);
    }

    closesocket(Connection);
    WSACleanup();

    return iExitCode;
}
```

```
/////////////////////Server Code///////////////////////////////

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool sendAll(SOCKET s, const void *buf, int size)
{
    const char *ptr = (const char*) buf;
    while (size > 0)
    {
        int numSent = send(s, ptr, size, NULL);
        if (numSent == SOCKET_ERROR) return false;
        ptr += numSent;
        size -= numSent;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    //WinSock Startup
    WSAData wsaData;
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 1), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) //If WSAStartup returns anything other than 0, then that means an error has occured in the WinSock Startup.
    {
        std::cout << "WinSock Startup Failed, Error " << iResult << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKADDR_IN addr = {};
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET; //IPv4 Socket
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //Address that we will bind our listening socket to. INADDR_ANY = all local IPv4 addresses
    addr.sin_port = htons(139); //Port

    SOCKET sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); //Create socket to listen for new connections
    if (sListen == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cout << "Failed to Create Socket, Error " << iResult << std::endl;
        closesocket(sListen);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    if (bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) //Bind the address to the socket
    {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cout << "Failed to Bind Socket, Error " << iResult << std::endl;
        closesocket(sListen);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    if (listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR) //Places sListen socket in a state in which it is listening for an incoming connection. Note:SOMAXCONN = Socket Outstanding Max Connections
    {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        std::cout << "Failed to Listen, Error " << iResult << std::endl;
        closesocket(sListen);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET newConnection; //Socket to hold the client's connection
    int iExitCode = 0;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Waiting for Client to Connect..." << std::endl;

        int addrlen = sizeof(addr); //length of the address (required for accept call)

        newConnection = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen); //Accept a new connection
        if (newConnection == INVALID_SOCKET) //If accepting the client connection failed
        {
            iResult = WSAGetLastError();
            std::cout << "Failed to accept a client's connection, Error " << iResult << std::endl;
            iExitCode = 1;
            break;
        }

        std::cout << "Client Connected!" << std::endl;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; ++counter)
        {
            std::string MOTD = "Hi there."; //Create buffer with message 

            if (!sendAll(newConnection, MOTD.c_str(), MOTD.length()+1))
            {
                iResult = WSAGetLastError();
                std::cout << "Failed to Send, Error " << iResult << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }

        closesocket(newConnection);
        std::cout << "Client Disconnected!" << std::endl;
    }
    while (true);

    closesocket(sListen);
    WSACleanup();

    return iExitCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the answers and comments! I solved the problem via changing the port number. Apparently, some of the port numbers are reserved so I have to assign another one.